# Deleting specific items from list using pop

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops

I have a school assignment to delete a specific element from an inputted list. Here are the specifics:

What you have to do:

1. Input a list, with at least one element repeating itself at least two times
2. Delete the last occurrence of that element from the list

For example:
  If the input is [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8]
  The output should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 8]

However, you can't:

1. Use deletion methods on the list except for pop; del, remove, etc are not allowed
2. Reverse the list, you have to read it from left to right

Here's what I've got so far:

```
l=[]
mid=0
found=0
for m in range(0,10):
    num=int(input("Enter the numbers for the list(10)"))
    l.append(num)
nan=int(input("Enter the number which u want to remove"))
for i in range(0,10):
    if l[i]==nan:
        mid=i
for j in range(mid,10):
    if l[j]==nan:
        found=1
        mid=j
        for k in range(mid,9):
            l[k]=l[k+1]
        break
    if nan not in l:
        found==-1
if found==1:
    l.pop()
    print (l)
if found==-1:
    print("Number doesnt exist in given list")
```

But I don't understand how the program isn't working. It should be deleting the second occurrence of the inputted element, not the last one.

For say, if the list is: [1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2, 9, 10]
Shouldn't the outcome be: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 9, 10]?
If not, why?
If someone could explain that to me, it'd be a great help!

Comment: Do you want the last instance of the item deleted, or the second one?

Comment: The last one is to be deleted.

Comment: The program however, is deleting the last one. But I don't know WHY or HOW. That's what I need an explanation for

Comment: So you don't know why it's doing what you want it to do

Comment: your program looks unnecessarily complicated. Once you know the number you want to delete, in only 5 line you can identify its last position and delete it

Comment: I know it can be done easier, but my professor has put up some restrictions , that I've mentioned in the post.

Comment: even under those restriction, 5 line are enough, 4 line are dedicated to find the last position of the element and the °5 line is pop operation... wait you change it, well now are 8 lines, the same 4 lines as before and the last 4 to make a copy of the list excluding the element in the position you found. And if you can use list comprehension it reduce again to 5 lines

Comment: Can you  provide the code? I've only just begun with python and am totally lost right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8]
seen = set()
duplicates = []
remove_after_occurrence = 3

for number in l:
    if number not in seen:
        seen.add(number)
    else:
        if number not in duplicates:
            duplicates.append(number)

counter = 0
for remove in duplicates:
    for index, number in enumerate(l):
        if remove == number:
            counter += 1
        if counter == remove_after_occurrence:
            l.pop(index)
            counter = 0

print(l)
print(seen)
print(duplicates)
```

This solution uses a set to indicate the duplicate values. And after removes the duplicate values in the list with pop. It is a little bit easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = dict()
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8]

for i, element in enumerate(elements):
   if elements.count( element ) > 1:
        d[element] = i

for j in d.values():
   elements.pop( j )

print elements
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/Zfm0BI)

This store the index of duplicate elements with latest one and remove then one by one.